# Node error : Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, node-modules

Whenever I'm trying to execute any node commands/create new angular project I'm getting the below error.
Node version **20.11.0**
NPM version **10.2.4**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create angular 13 projects specifically? Why not a newer version?

Comment: I tried creating new blank project also but still not able to create new project. It gives the same error. invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli reason: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Comment: Have you tried running it from powershell? It looks like you're using cmd now

Answer (score 1):

It was related to proxy. After adding the below commands I was able to create new project as well as install node modules.
No need to downgrade Node in my case.

```
> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

> npm config set https-proxy https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 13 supports only upto  `^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0` please install within `node 12 - node 16` and retry the command, maybe it will work!

[Angular node compatibility reference link](https://angular.io/guide/versions)

---

Alternative solution will be you install the latest angular the steps are as follows

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Optionally you can install core module also

```
npm install -g @angular/core@latest
```

Then you can retry the command and see if it works!

Comment: I had installed Node 16.16.0 for Angular 15.2.10 still it gave me the same issue "invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli reason: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON". To try out i updated my node version to the latest one.

Comment: @deepdalvi Could you try the second approach?

Comment: yes Naren tried the second approch same error gets thrown

Comment: @deepdalvi Alternative you could try `ng new myApp --routing`, you can remove routing if its not needed! please make sure you have the latest versions of `node`, `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the script (`npm` in this case) is expecting JSON, but is getting HTML instead. The bigger question is what is in that HTML document; maybe advice to use latest Angular version... who knows!